# Is possible to use messages in a class procedure?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want use `messages`in my program and i've a question: Can I use messages in a `class procedure` or Can I use `messages` in a `procedure` without `class`?

Here is my code:

```
const

  WM_CUSTOM_TCP_CLIENT = WM_USER + 10;

type
    TFeedbackEvent = class
      public
        class procedure feedback(var msg: TMessage); message WM_CUSTOM_TCP_CLIENT;
      end;
```

The Delphi returns the following message:

```
[Error] unit.pas(33): Invalid message parameter list
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can probably answer this yourself. Remove `class` from before `procedure` and compile, and it works. Add `class` back again and it doesn't. What's unclear? (I'm not the one who downvoted, BTW. Just curious what part you needed to have clarified.)

Comment: Thank you for your help @KenWhite. Do you know if can I use the `procedure` catching `message` outside a class? `procedure` of `unit`? Thank you again for your support.

Comment: No, you can't. The procedure has to be a method of an object to use the `message` directive. (You could again check this yourself.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you post answer for me upvote your help?

Comment: @qasoft has written a very good answer. You should upvote that answer instead; it provides more details than my comments. Thanks for the offer, though. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very nice article on the topic: [Handling Messages in Delphi 6](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27795). This is a must read.

> Handling or processing a message means that your application responds
>   in some manner to a Windows message. In a standard Windows
>   application, message handling is performed in each window procedure.
>
> By internalizing the window procedure, however, Delphi makes it much
>   easier to handle individual messages; instead of having one procedure
>   that handles all messages, each message has its own procedure. Three
>   requirements must be met for a procedure to be a message-handling
>   procedure:
>
> - The procedure must be a method of an object.
> - The procedure must take one var parameter of a TMessage or other    message-specific record type.
> - The procedure must use the message directive followed by the constant    value of the message you want to process.

As you can read in the article, the procedure must be a method of an object, not a class. So you cannot just use message handlers in a class procedure.

---

A possible workaround to handle messages in a class instance (also in object instance or window-less applications), is to manually create window handle via AllocateHWND, and process messages yourself via a WndProc procedure.

There is a good example on this in delphi.about.com: [Sending messages to non-windowed applications (Page 2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611112838/http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa093003b.htm):

The following sample is a version of the above example, modified to work with class method. (If using class method is not really required, use original example from the link above instead):

First, you need to declare a window handle field and a WndProc procedure:

```
TFeedbackEvent = class
private
  FHandle: HWND;
protected
  class procedure ClassWndProc(var msg: TMessage); 
end;

procedure WndProc(var msg: TMessage);
```

Then, process the messages manually:

```
procedure WndProc(var msg: TMessage); 
begin
    TFeedbackEvent.ClassWndProc(msg);
end;

procedure TFeedbackEvent.ClassWndProc(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  if msg.Msg = WM_CUSTOM_TCP_CLIENT then
    // TODO: Handle your message
  else
    // Let default handler process other messages
    msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FHandle, msg.Msg, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
end;
```

Finally, at the end of the file, declare initialization and finalization section to create/destroy the handle:

```
initialization
    FHandle := AllocateHWND(WndProc);

finalization
    DeallocateHWnd(FHandle);
```

---

Of course, this is not the recommended way to do this (especially watch for problems with initialization/finalization), it was just an example to show that it is possible.

Unless you have some very strange requirement to use class method, its better to use regular class method and object constructor and destructor instead initialization and finalization sections (as shown in [Sending messages to non-windowed applications (Page 2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611112838/http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa093003b.htm)).